# How to move the autogenerated buttons in c# with mouse during runtime

Tags: c#, button, runtime, move

I'm generating buttons depending on rows in table in database ex. 5 rows (products) for 5 buttons (representing products). But now I want to move these buttons with mouse during runtime. I tried a lot of code but none helped me.

I'm new at this field and I'd be very happy if someone helps me.
btw this is my code

```
  private void ZgjedhTavoline_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //nxjerr krejt tavolinat nga databaza
        var sum = context.Tavolinats.Count();

        foreach (var row in context.Tavolinats)
        {
            //krijon buton per secilin tavoline
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Text = row.Emri_Tavolines;
            newButton.Size = new Size(flpTavolinat.Width/6,flpTavolinat.Height/4);
            newButton.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            newButton.BackColor = Color.Teal;
            newButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            newButton.Margin = new Padding(0);
            newButton.Font = new Font("Georgia", 12);

            //shton butona ne flow layout panel
            flpTavolinat.Controls.Add(newButton);


        }
        //ruan ndryshimet
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: This is the code for adding controls  to the `flpTavolinat` could you please share that code that failed to remove the button?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Button newButton = new Button();
 newButton.Text = "sample";
 this.AcceptButton = newButton;
 this.Controls.Add(newButton);
```

This will move the `mouse` or the `mouse focus` to your `newButton`

Comment: the op wants to move **control** with the mouse, not move the mouse.